# NodeJS ExpressJS EJS Tailwind not working

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, tailwind-css

I am working on a website and I am trying use tailwind with EJS as the viewer and it's not loading the CSS (It's what I am assuming) I have watched several Youtube videos and non of them have worked.

---

Tailwind Config file

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./views/*.{html,js,css} ",
    "./views/index.ejs",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [ {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
  }
  ]
}
```

Server.js File

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./views/*.{html,js,css} ",
    "./views/index.ejs",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [ {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
  }
  ]
}
```

Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "person-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "build-tail": "SET NODE_ENV=production tailwindcss build -i /styles/tailwindcss.css -o /assets/styles.css"
  },
  "author": "Thomas Murray",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

> [My file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMY2j.png)

It just keeps loading the HTML/EJS file and the CSS

Comment: server.js should have your express code in it. Also share your ejs contents (minimally)